# Netezza to Redshift Conversion - _v_table and _v_relation_columns alternatives

Tags: amazon-redshift, netezza, system-tables

What are the alternatives for the below Netezza Tables and columns that I could use in Redshift?

- _v_table (columns used: 'RELVERSION' and 'OBJTYPE')
- _v_relation_columns (columns used: 'NAME' and  'ATTNAME')

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to Netezza's _v_table could be `SVV_ALL_TABLES` in Redshift. There's no `relversion` attribute because tables aren't versioned. (So you don't need to groom versions after adding a column).

And as a replacement for `_v_relation_column` you could use the `information_schema.columns` table.